Moving to robotics with a background in mathematics and physics
I'm a first-semester mathematics student at a Technical university in Germany, and I also have a bachelor's in physics.
I've always been interested in robotics, and now I'm taking an introductory course in robotics (forward and inverse kinematics/ PID control/ dynamics etc.). Since I like it very much, and I'm seeing that lots of topics I covered in my bachelor's could be really useful (lagrangian/Hamiltonian/newtonian mechanics, dynamical systems, electronics, data analysis etc.) I was thinking about making it my career.
I wanted to ask several questions, or better, get an overview of various topics:

Given my background and my current education, which areas of robotics do you think could be better suited for me/ could I access? Are there any growing fields related to my background?

Which courses do you think I should take?


For mathematical courses, I took the basics for physicists, then I took differential geometry. I'm planning on taking courses in probability theory and statistics and some courses in machine learning and deep learning/ visual computing (to get a general education). So, apart from the basics in maths, which mathematical courses do you think could be useful? Which courses that are not usually in a mathematics/physics degree should I take, depending on the various specializations?

What are the best ways to get experience in the field as a person with my background?

feel free to ask more questions about me/ my courses!
Thank you

this might help you ... https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tour

just pick whatever interests you the most and then fill in any necessary education

I'll answer question 3 and that will guide you to answer 1 and 2 yourself:
BAFAR™  (Build A F***ing Awesome Robot) that solves a problem that you care about. It could be anything from fetching you a beer (killer application) to helping save lives (https://vimeo.com/showcase/11451831/video/1024971800).
You can start with a simulation and progress to real hardware as you learn.
Very soon you will find things that you need to learn (and then you can search for specific courses) and things that you absolutely love and can build a career around.
As I always say: One who has the will can achieve more than one who has the skill
